# how to get data from sqlite database in ANDROID ??

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i am working with sqlite database in Android for first time, i have create my database in Sqlite and copy it to android "Asset", i want to get the data from database with "click" the "Button", i have one table contain 4 field "ID, Location, Lattitude, Longitude", but im not able to get any data from.
in my xml, i make two "edit text" for insert data "lattitude" and "longitude" and then Button "search" to get data Location from database.
but im not able to get any data.
im new to android
please help me

here i post my code

DBAdapter

```
package com.joel.databases;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBAdapter {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.tracking/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "tracking.sqlite";
private SQLiteDatabase db; 
//private final Context myContext;
private DBAdapter DBHelper;
private final Context context;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DBAdapter(context);
    //super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    //this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        /*By calling this method and empty database will be created into            the          default system path
          of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        */
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database file.");
        }
      }
     } 

private void getReadableDatabase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,            
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myinput =               
     context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.tracking 
     /databases/"+ context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +"/databases
     /tracking.sqlite");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();


  }

  public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
      //Open the database
      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
      db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }


    public synchronized void close() {
    if(db != null) db.close();
    db.close();
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
    }
```

and this my database.java

```
   package com.joel.databases;

   //import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
   import com.joel.databases.R;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
   import android.database.Cursor;

    public class databases extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Button cari;
private databases this_class = this;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
    db.openDataBase();

    cari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cari);
     // cari.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    //public void onClick(View v){
    InitDatabase();
    }



     public void InitDatabase() {
     AsyncTask<String, Void, String> InitDB = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        Dialog progress = null;
        String msg;
        DBAdapter db_adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            db_adapter = new DBAdapter(this_class);
            if (!db_adapter.checkDataBase())
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(this_class, "", "Installing 
         Database.\nPlease wait.");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                db_adapter.createDataBase();
                msg = "Database successfully installed.";
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                msg = "Database installation failed.";
            }
            return msg;
         }

          @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progress!=null) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
          }
         };
        InitDB.execute(new String());
         } 

         }
```

Comment: Please post any logcat errors.

Comment: Do you have a class that extends to a SQLiteOpenHelper? because SQLiteOpenHelper allows you to create the actual database, query them and so on.

Comment: Have a look at the android tutorial on the link below
Android App Development Tutorial To Retrieve Data From Sqlite In Android App
[http://jannatyahan.com/android-app-development-tutorial-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-in-android/](http://jannatyahan.com/android-app-development-tutorial-to-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-in-android/)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
```

instead of

```
 OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.tracking 
     /databases/"+ context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +"/databases
     /tracking.sqlite");
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

it explains how to use and access an independent, preloaded database with your Android application.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, what you are trying to achieve is far beyond your level - my honest and unwanted advice is: spend some time programming simple things on some simpler platform. This way you can move ahead without asking people for help all the time. And moving ahead on your own is the only thing that will make you learn at all.

Then study some Java (just the basics, but both the language and bits around it, like naming conventions).

Then come back to Android. Suddenly, all the tutorials and api docs will start making sense to you.